# spring integration inbound file channel adapter thread hangs

Tags: spring-integration

we are using inbound channel adapter to poll for file and once we have file we do make db call. If we have problem with db connection, that thread just hangs and never poll the file again.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="testChannel"
    directory="/nas/test"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    prevent-duplicates="false"
    filter="testFileFilter"
    >
    <int:poller id="poller" cron="0/30 * * * * *" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: That does not make sense for me, because having such a problem in the framework we would receive a lot bad feedback. Looks like an issue in you code between `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` and that DB call. Maybe you try to obtain DB connection in the infinite loop?..

Comment: Take a thread dump; you will most likely see the thread hung somewhere.

Comment: Here how my code looks like, once we poll file one at a time, filter is making db call to see if it should be processed or not. But i think this is all happening in one thread based on my config and that thread is not able to get db connection. After 15 min we got exception and that thread never returned back to pool for next cycle of polling

Comment: We've run into a similar issue. Has anyone found a resolution?